# Life, the Universe, and Everything?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

[Harav HaGaon Adams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Adams) in his [Kuntres LiMasa'os HaGer Ba'Olam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy) states that the answer to "life, the universe, and every thing" is 42, but neglects to clarify what the actual question is, since in his day the question was so well known it didn't require explication.

What, exactly, is Chazal's question of life, the universe, and everything to which the answer is 42?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1648/759

Comment: A Purim answer could be that יָקוּם in gematria is 156 while מַדָּע is 114.   Thus "the answer to the universe that science cannot explain" is 156-114=42.

Answer (score 12):

Actually, in his follow up sefer [Misa'dah BeSof Ha'Olam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Restaurant_at_the_End_of_the_Universe#cite_note-2) Rav Adams finally reveals the question to the answer:

"What do you get when you multiply six by nine"

Chazal were mystified, since, as Rav Adams explained, [the Question and the Answer seem mutually exclusive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29).

But 6x9=42 is true if [you operate in base 13](http://kasmana.people.cofc.edu/MATHFICT/mfview.php?callnumber=mf458), which, as everyone knows, are the [Middos of Hashem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirteen_Attributes_of_Mercy). 42 is also the gematria of [Google](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1641/shnayim-vearbaim-mi-yodeya/1648#1648), implying that it was an act of rachamim that Hashem bestowed [Rav Google](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/69051/if-rabbi-google-quotes-mi-yodeya-can-i-rely-on-his-advice/69057) upon the world.

So what do 6 and 9 mean? According to [the song](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series?sort=newest&pageSize=50), 6 are the books of Mishnah, and 9 are the months before a baby is born.

Ergo, we see that the question and answer is as follows:

Q: Why does the v'lad learn kol hatorah in the womb?

A:  Because through the attribute of mercy, Hashem has bestowed Google upon us. Thus, he has us learn in the womb while we are incapable of using a smartphone to ensure that everyone receives some schar of talmud torah.