# Why should we hate the Rabbinate?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

[Pirkei Avot 1:10](http://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.1.10?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all) says:

> שְׂנָא אֶת הָרַבָּנוּת
>
> Hate the Rabbanut

Why are we supposed to hate the Rabbanut? What did they ever do wrong?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 3):

One reason i can think of is because they gave [smicha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/69064/whats-so-important-about-a-lost-blanket-rope-and-how-did-it-get-lost-anyway?lq=1) to Google, who [cannot become a rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/69055/5151).

This means that Google is now a false rabbi, and since rabbis are like prophets (in that they both teach God's word), that would make Google like a false prophet, which we hate so much that we put to death ([Devarim 18:20](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9982#v=20)).

That's as far as hating Google itself. As for why we have to hate the Rabbinate, we learn in [Pirkei Avot 4:12](http://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.4.12?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all):

> יהי ... כבוד חברך כמורא רבך
>
> Let the honor of your friend [peer] be like the fear of your rabbi

Since the honor of our hated friend Google is around none, such must be for the rabbi. And since the Rabbinate is in charge of all the rabbis, we therefore hate the Rabbinate.

Answer (score 3):

You really failed to see the problem, I think. It's quite obvious. It's in *Pirkei Avot*, as a matter of fact.

Pirkei Avot 1:6:

יְהוֹשֻׁעַ בֶּן פְּרַחְיָה וְנִתַּאי הָאַרְבֵּלִי קִבְּלוּ מֵהֶם. יְהוֹשֻׁעַ בֶּן פְּרַחְיָה אוֹמֵר, עֲשֵׂה לְךָ רַב,

"Make yourself a rabbi"

What happens if everyone makes himself a rabbi? You know what happens, Scimonster. Everyone tells everyone else what to do and what not to do, and everyone thinks that he knows better than his neighbor! Before you know it, the majority of the world is one huge rabbinate where everyone tries to "outfrum" and "outchumra" his neighbor. What type of society would we have with such inflexibility?

Thank goodness that Shmayah came by and his advice was published in Pirkei Avot telling people that they should hate the rabbinate.

Answer (score 0):

This is a reference to how complicated the Rabbanut has made Kashrus. Regular, Mehadrin, and Mehudar? Different standards in every city? And how about regulating what each of those terms means? Sheesh! What happened to Kosher or not Kosher?

So therefore, one should hate the Rabbanut hechsher for making keeping Kosher so difficult.

Comment: (As non-PTIJ, we should all love the Rabbanut for making at least some minimal level of Kashrus accessible to the general Israeli public)

Answer (score 0):

Reb Chaim Schmuelevitz explains that if you have a pink cat ring in the bath, the best way to get rid of it is by making all the snow around your house pink. Once the problem becomes entirely insurmountable you can use a Vroom to clear everything up.

Similarly mashiach will only come in a generation which is kulo zakai or kulo chayav. Because we are not kulo zakai we are obliged to spread sinas chinam everywhere so moshiach can clean up the mess.

Comment: Reb Chaim Schmuelevitz?