# Is PDF avodah zarah (idol worship)?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

A good rabbi always anticipates questions before they're asked, so when you start asking [Rabbi Google](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/69051/if-rabbi-google-quotes-mi-yodeya-can-i-rely-on-his-advice) "how do i convert to...", he's quick to suggest Judaism. And Islam. And Christianity. And PDF.

[image: how do i convert to pdf suggestion]

So now the question is, is it permissible to convert to PDF, or is it *avodah zarah*?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Of course you should convert to a [probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function)! It's not *avoda zara*; in fact, in many cases it's [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution). Though conversion is difficult from a [logistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_distribution) point of view, it's not [hyperbolic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_distribution) to say that you'll [uniform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous))ly find [exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) returns on the effort expended (*l'fum tzaara agra*). But to get conversion right to a *[t](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution)*, you must first be a conversion [student](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution). Then, after conversion, you'll be awarded a new life (*k'katan shenolad dame*), thus a *[chai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution)* [squared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution).

Answer (score 12):

Not only is the [Planetary Defence Force](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Planetary_Defence_Force) not *avodah zara*, but defense is an obligatory war.  For a discretionary war your conversion to a soldier would be declined if you're a newlywed, have just planted a vineyard or built a house, or are frightened, but defending your homeland is not discretionary.  For an obligatory war "all go forth, even the bridegroom out of his chamber and the bride from her bridal pavilion" (Mish., Sot. 8:8) (according to [here](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/military-law)).

That's all who are at least 20 years old, though, so if you're underage, it's forbidden but still not *avodah zarah*.

Answer (score 5):

The word "convert" is in Hebrew to Shmad, from the word להשמיד - to destroy. The reason is that whenever one converts, he destroys his past (Mitzvos - in most conversions to idolatry).

Why is one not allowed to convert out of Judaism? The simple answer is because of Baal Tashchis, one destroys his past Mitzvos.

Now, regarding converting to PDF, there's the same calculation.

When one converts to PDF, he's also losing his past (Undo, for example). So it is also forbidden because of Baal Tashchis.

Answer (score 4):

Yes PDF is an Aramaic initials Pulchan De Famalia.  The prohibition to draw or sculpt mador haelion(¹) (see poskim about the lav lo taassun iti)  or mador hatachton is because of the natural choice of those pieces of the universe for avoda (= pulchan in Aramaic) . mador in hebrew is pamalia in Aramaic. See Ramban on Shemot 20, 5.

see [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/72933/9215) post, and [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/72924/9215)

---

(¹)Ramban Shemot 20. 05 says that angels were the first idols:

> הראשונים החלו לעבוד את המלאכים שהם השכלים הנבדלים בעבור שידעו למקצתם שררה על האומות, כענין שכתוב (דניאל י כ) שר מלכות יון ושר מלכות פרס, וחשבו שיש להם יכולת בם להיטיב או להרע, וכל אחד עובד לשר שלו כי היו הראשונים יודעים אותם, ואלה הם הנקראים בתורה ובכתובים כלם אלהים אחרים, אלהי העמים, כי המלאכים נקראים אלהים, כמו שנאמר הוא אלהי האלהים (דברים י יז), השתחוו לו כל אלהים (תהלים צז ז), כי גדול ה' מכל האלהים (לעיל יח יא). ואע''פ שהיו העובדים מודים שהכח הגדול והיכולת הגמורה לאל עליון, וכך אמרו רבותינו (מנחות קי:) דקרו ליה אלה דאלהיא, ובזה אמר הכתוב זובח לאלהים יחרם הזכירם בשם הידיעה: ‏

(²) op.  cit. the stars according to Ramban:

> והמין השני בע''ז, שחזרו לעבוד לצבא השמים הנראה, מהם עובדי השמש או הירח, ומהם למזל מן המזלות, כי כל אחת מן האומות ידעה כח המזל בה כפי משטרו על הארץ שלהם, וחשבו כי בעבודתם יגבר המזל ויועיל להם, כענין שכתוב (ירמיה ח ב) ושטחום לשמש ולירח ולכל צבא השמים אשר אהבום ואשר עבדום ואשר הלכו אחריהם ואשר דרשום ואשר השתחוו להם, וכמו שנאמר בתורה באיסור של ע''ז (דברים ד יט) ופן תשא עיניך השמימה וראית את השמש ואת הירח ואת הכוכבים כל צבא השמים ונדחת והשתחוית להם ועבדתם אשר חלק ה' אלהיך אותם לכל העמים תחת כל השמים. יאמר, כי בעבור שחלק השם אותם לכל העמים ונתן לכל עם כוכב ומזל לא תהיה נדח אחריהם לעבדם, ואלה האנשים הם שהחלו לעשות הצורות הרבות בפסילים והאשרים והחמנים, כי היו עושים צורות מזלם בשעות אשר להם הכח כפי מעלתם, והיו נותנים בעם, כפי מחשבתם, כח והצלחה: ‏

Answer (score 4):

It is shituf, not AZ (per the Rambam) because a PDF is not saying that it is the document itself, only a *format* of the document.